# Yammer API wrapper

Tags: python, yammer

is the Yampy package, yammer-API wrapper for python still maintained?
Authorization is easily completed, but I try to get messages from a certain user only.

The reccomended way of doing so is using the messages factory (described here: http://pythonhosted.org/yampy/api.html#yampy.apis.MessagesAPI)

eg. `messages.from_user()` or `messages.sent()`

```python
yamm = yampy.Yammer(access_token=session.get('yammer_access_token'))
user_id = current_user.get(u'id')
msgs_dict = yamm.messages.from_user(user_id=user_id, limit=limit)
msgs =  msgs_dict.get(u'messages')
for msg in msgs:
    print msg.get(u'sender_id')
    print "-----------------------------------"

bla= yamm.messages.sent(limit=limit).get(u'messages')
for blu in bla:
    print blu.get(u'sender_id')
    print "-----------------------------------"
```

The output of both of them is the same, and both of them don't match the user_id and the sender_id

The Output will look like this:

```
user_id   
"-----------------------------------"
user_id2
"-----------------------------------"
user_id3
"-----------------------------------"
another_user_id
"-----------------------------------"
```

only one or two of the messages will actually match the wanted user_id of the *current_user*

The last commit has been 1 year back and I'm having doubts.

Comment: Okay, I manually constructed the call to the API-endpoint and I get same result, so it's not a problem with the library, but seems to be something with the `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/sent.json` endpoint

Comment: I think you are going to have to run through that and filter by user ID at the moment :( The Yammer UI used to have a way to view your sent posts, but this was removed and likely affected the API.

Comment: Well, seems to be a general problem with the filtering after the user_id, `yamm.messages.from_user(user_id=user_id)` will also return only messages from the stream of the user, but not sent by the user.
When combining this with the fact that you can only get a maximum of 20 messages per call from yammer and <a href=https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-ratelimits>this</a>, "Apps that poll excessively will be blocked.", this may lead to unexpected results.